# Unique in hql query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I did a hql query and I am getting this:

```
Persona con id=42: Hannah Abbott
Persona con id=1: Euan Abercrombie
Persona con id=56: Stewart Ackerley
Persona con id=56: Stewart Ackerley
Persona con id=73: Malcolm Baddock
Persona con id=57: Marcus Belby
Persona con id=57: Marcus Belby
Persona con id=57: Marcus Belby
```

As you can see, I am getting duplicates.

```
ScrollableResults sc = session.createQuery("from Person as p join p.courses_1 as c order by p.lastName asc ").scroll();
```

This is the query.

I've tried putting distinct on the hql query but it doesn't work.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of an inner join, the `distinct` keyword should work here:

```java
String hql = "select distinct p from Person as p inner join p.courses_1 as c order by p.lastName";
ScrollableResults sc = session.createQuery(hql).scroll();
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I needed to wait to accept it and I forgot. Many thanks again!